# Descriptive analysis of one-hot encoded categorical variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that contains three categorical variables and one numeric variable. The categorical variables are one-hot encoded.
They're: `SolarDevice`, `Generator` & `PortableBattery`.

```
SolarDevice <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
Generator <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
PortableBattery <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
MonthlyExpense <- c(500, 620, 370, 566, 622)
EnergyExpenseDB <- data.frame(SolarDevice, Generator, PortableBattery, MonthlyExpense)
```

I'd like to generate descriptive statistics (min, mean, median, max) of these three categorical variables using the data present in the column `MonthlyExpense`.

I haven't tried it because I don't know how to go about it. Anyone who has an approach on this using `dplyr` or any other technique I welcome it.

Comment: try `summary(EnergyExpenseDB)` or `collapse::qsu(EnergyExpenseDB)`